# Отправка собщения по клику на Enter из Textarea в JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

У меня есть форма ввода сообщения Textarea. **Сообщение должно отправляться по клику на "Enter", а перенос строки должен быть на "Enter + Shift"**. Как в социальных сетях и мессенджерах, например, Вконтакте или Telegram.

Чтобы отследить клик я использую (e.keyCode + событие в Vue Js).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnMFX.png)

**На ПК работает все отлично** - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gUBqN-o2zlHS5pGhFSofpLhhbVlLQoeC/view?usp=sharing
(Текст переносится на Enter + Shift и отправляется на Enter)

---

На телефоне при клике на Enter **нужно переносить на новую строчку**, сейчас это работает так:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ze7Hj9NJQkDQ4MBpzFgB3o7SZfAEnwQv/view?usp=sharing

Чтобы на телефоне перенести на новую строку нужно тоже зажимать Enter + Shift, но это очень неудобно. Нужно найти решение.

Пример из Telegram:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12HzPplkCOZvjAXz3lZF1xAuHTfEH6fO6/view?usp=sharing

Пробовал:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934088/how-to-make-enter-key-in-a-textarea-submit-a-form
https://tallpad.com/series/tiny-tips/lessons/submit-form-on-textarea-enter-vuejs

Comment: что мешает при нажатии проверять `window.innerWidth` и при определенном условии немного изменять скрипт?

Comment: Хм, интересно, но что мы от этого получим? Из ширины найти телефон? А если это планшет или какой-то большой монитор с виртуальной клавиатурой? В примерах (Вконтакте) не зависит от ширины, используется какой-то другой метод. Или вы имеете ввиду определять таким образом виртуальную клавиатуру ?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему через определение устройства
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)